# Can't use subscribe from inside c++ class

Tags: ros, subscribe, roscpp, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having trouble getting ros inside a c++ class.
Running Windows 7, compiling with Visual Studio 2010.

I started by trying to adapt the "listener" project in rosws, which contains a visualstudio example that compiles and runs ok.

However, even if I simply put everything inside a class, I get this error:

```
Error   30  error C2660: 'ros::NodeHandle::subscribe' : function does not take 3 arguments  C:\opt\rosws\fuerte\sdk-tutorials\listener\listener.cpp 59  1   listener
```

This simple example replicates the problem:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <sstream>

class listener {
    public:
    void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
    {
        ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
    }

    int mymain(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        ros::init(argc, argv, "listener");
        ros::NodeHandle n;
        ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter", 1000, &listener::chatterCallback);
        ros::spin();

        return 0;
    }
};
```

So you see that I am just sticking everything inside a class so that I can create and manipulate instances of my objects.

Why does the compiler not find the correct subscribe function now? If I just compile the code without the class, it works.

I checked out the "talker" project which used an "advertise" function, but that one works ok if I stick it inside a class.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47361/can%27t-use-subscribe-from-inside-c++-class/) by [TiagoRibeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3310/tiagoribeiro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-11-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to pass the class pointer along with the callback:

```
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter", 1000, &listener::chatterCallback, this);
```

EDIT: I missed the fact that you are compiling on Windows. I have no idea if that interface is officially supported on VS2010.

Your work-around is not really a solution. If you actually want to use ROS on Windows, please open a defect ticket so the maintainers know their code does not work with your compiler.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TiagoRibeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3310/tiagoribeiro/) on 2012-11-07**:
You are right. Can you please direct me to where I should post the ticket? I found the ticket handoffs but didn't quite understand where I should post this as a ticket.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-11-07**:
Sure: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/newticket?component=ros_comm&type=defect&&ros_comm

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found that while looking through the node_handle class code, but I still got the same error.
It was like of the compiler was just trying to match the parameters with the 1-parameter version that takes in only a SubscribeOptions object.

Actually I ended up added the following:

```
template<class M, class C> Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, void(*fp)(const boost::shared_ptr<M const>&));
```

to the "ros\fuerte\x86\include\ros\node_handle.h" file, right after to line 785 which contains:

```
Subscriber subscribe(SubscribeOptions& ops);
```

I haven't messed around with C++ for some years now, been mainly working in C# so I'm not really sure what is the issue, it just seemed to me that if I was inside another class/namespace, the compiler wasn't finding all the versions of the function because they are all templated, and just found this one on line 785, so I tried replicating it for the version I wanted..
It compiled correctly and is now working.

Interestingly, I was still forced to add the class pointer parameter, as without it, the compiler produces the same error.

Maybe I should take some lessons on templates, because right now this just seems like creepy stuff to me :)

Anyway, problem solved.
Thanks for the support!

---

Originally posted by [TiagoRibeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3310/tiagoribeiro/) with karma: 41 on 2012-11-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TiagoRibeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3310/tiagoribeiro/) on 2012-11-02**:
Don't have enough points to accept my own answer, but this was the solution.